# How to connect Edge and Safari to a Selenium Grid running on a AWS Linux instance?

Tags: selenium, docker-compose, selenium-grid

Who to connect Edge and Safari to a Selenium Grid running on a AWS Linux instance?

I have a requirement to do multi-browser testing (only Chrome, Firefox, Edge & Safari) for my selenium tests in AWS env. Currently I have a selenium grid running on a AWS Linux instance with Chrome and Firefox node containers, spawn through docker-compose v2. To get the other two browsers satisfied (Edge & Safari)  I'm looking for a solution.

For Edge testing, I'm thinking that I can create a Win Server instance and get Edge (https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-msedge-msedgedriver) running it in. But still not sure this can act as a node registered to a hub running in a different instance. I'm trying this and still no luck.

For Safari, current thinking is setting up a physical Mac machine. I'm trying this and still no luck.

Maybe there is a better approach to get Edge & Safari to the Grid. Appreciate any suggestion or directions.